# ipaddress module ValueError('%s has host bits set' % self)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip-address

I am trying to list valid hosts for given network range via Python3, `ipaddress` module but I am getting ValueError `ValueError('%s has host bits set' % self)`
while trying to list all valid hosts.

```
>>> ip_range=input("Enter IP Range:")
Enter IP Range:192.168.56.101/16
>>> list(ipa.ip_network(ip_range).hosts())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ipaddress.py", line 74, in ip_network
    return IPv4Network(address, strict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ipaddress.py", line 1536, in __init__
    raise ValueError('%s has host bits set' % self)
ValueError: 192.168.56.101/16 has host bits set
```

Comment: Not sure if this should be a comment, or an answer, or possibly better a link to decent documentation. IP addresses have two parts, "network part" and "host part". The network part comes first, and the host part comes second. The number after the `/` indicates how many of the bits are "the network part". That's, essentially, the part used for routing. The host part is for finding a host, once you've found the network.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.ip_network):

> A ValueError is raised if address does not represent a valid IPv4 or
>   IPv6 address, or **if the network has host bits set.**

The number after slash(16 in your case) means, number of bits reserved for [subnet](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Subnet), so last 16 bits are your host bits. This method requires those bits as 0 (unset).

Comment: so you mean I have to enter network range as 192.168.56.101/0 ? I am not good with network concepts.

Comment: `192.168.0.0/16` is what you want most likely.

Answer (score 27):

You have another option.
From the [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network) mentioned above, we can see that:

> If strict is True and host bits are set in the supplied address, then
>   ValueError is raised. Otherwise, the host bits are masked out to
>   determine the appropriate network address.

So, please try following again.

```
ip_range = '192.168.56.101/16'
list(ipaddress.ip_network(ip_range, False).hosts())
```

Answer (score 12):

## Two Solutions

Either you change your input or the code.

### 1: Changing the input

Above you mentioned your input being `192.168.56.101/16`. The `16` defines the host bits for this ip-range. Python wants you to clear them (set all those bits to 0). Your specified the ip as `192.168.56.101`, while telling there were `16` host bits. Python expected the last `16` bits to be `0`.

In binary the Ip looks like this: `11000000.10101000.00111000.01100101`. **You need to clear the last 16 bits.** It then looks like this: `11000000.10101000.0.0` (equal to `192.168.0.0` in decimal).

**Concluding:** You would need to change your input to `192.168.0.0/16` for it to properly work.

### 2: Changing the code

Looking at the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network):

> If strict is True and host bits are set in the supplied address, then
>   ValueError is raised. Otherwise, the host bits are masked out to
>   determine the appropriate network address.

So deactivate the *strict* mode by changing your code:

Change `ip_network(target)` to `ip_network(target, False)`.

Here you could technically input `192.168.56.101/16`.

### References

- Similar question: [python-port-scanner-will-not-accept-address-range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61776557/12787264)
- A tool to [convert Ips to binary](https://www.browserling.com/tools/ip-to-bin)

---

*This answer is late, but I believe it is helpful!*

Answer (score 0):

The IP that you are trying to push actually "isn't valid" and doesn't match the prefix (/16).

Loading it with the "no strict" `False` - will actually provide the network/prefix that *should* have been provided as an input.

Wanted to share another example to overcome a wrong input from the user's side, using the `netaddr` module

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork

f = IPNetwork("192.168.56.101/16")
network = list(f.subnet(16))[0]
print(network)       <= from this point i would work with this variable

# -- output --
IPNetwork('192.168.0.0/16')
```